# How to highlight in a column percentages that differ more than 5% using conditional formatting?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

How to highlight in a column percentages that differ more than 5% using conditional formatting?

```
Amsterdam   78000   68000   70000   71000   287000  290000     -1.03%
Berlin      45000   38000   36000   37000   156000  154000      1.30%
Brussels    74000   71000   72000   73000   290000  289000      0.35%
London      93000   91000   89000   88000   361000  342000      5.56%
Paris       102000  98000   94000   94000   388000  420000     -7.62%
```

Comment: What is your expected output? highlighting rows London and Paris? Do you have already the % calculated?

Comment: Yes the variation was calculated now I need to highlight the ones in which the variation differs more than 5 % - which I already know is (-7.62) and (5.56) I just don't manage to do this...thanks a lot for your question;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am correct in assuming you want values >5.0% and values <-5.0%, you can create a new rule for your column that applies to values not between -5.0% and 5.0%.

[image: Conditional Formatting Rules Manager - example]

Comment: It worked !
Thanks a lot, I spent so many hours trying to figure this out and it was actually quite simple :)
THANK YOU

Comment: @Zoinc If this answer solved your problem, you should accept it by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer. Once you've done this, the check mark will turn green and you will earn 2 reputation.